# Need some explanation on how HashSet works

Tags: c#, collections

That is what I have:

```
class A
{
  // The uniqueness of instance must be detected by this property
  public string Key { get; set; }

  // There are other properties
}

var set = HashSet<A>()
```

My general purposes are:

- to provide identity of instances in the `set` collection by `Key` property value
- to make this collection work as fast as possible for Contain operation

Answer to the following questions might help me to meet this purposes:

1. What is used to run methods like `Contains` and `Add` which have to determine uniqueness of the instance: GetHashCode() or IEquatable? Most probably GetHashCode() as HashSet declared to be very fast for search.
2. Default `String.GetHashCode()` implementation does not guarantee uniqueness of hash for 2 different string, so how can I provide uniqueness with performance in mind?
3. Is IEquatable is used at all by HashSet?

Note his collection is created and destroyed in run-time only, it is not saved into Database

Comment: The more important question is can the value of `Key` change while a record is sitting in the collection?

Comment: Sorry for missing it: no, it can not

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Collections usually use `Object.GetHashCode()` and `Object.Equals()` to obtain hash codes and check for equality. There is no way to make `Object.GetHashCode()` return a unique hash code for all but the simplest objects - the hash code is only 32 bit wide and every object with more than 32 bits of internal state can not be mapped to unique hash codes. Therefore `Object.Equals()` is used to check for exact equality in case of hash code collisions.

In consequence you have to override both mentioned methods with a suitable implementation.

```
public override Int32 GetHashCode()
{
    // If this.Key may be null you have to handle this case.
    return this.Key.HashCode();
}

public override Boolean Equals(Object obj)
{
    var other = obj as A;

    return (other != null) && (this.Key == other.Key);
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `HashSet<T>` constructor accepting `IEqualityComparer<T>` and externalize both methods, for example if you have no control over the source code of the types you want to add to a set. Just create a class implementing the interface with suitable methods and pass an instance of this class to the `HashSet<T>` constructor.

Comment: Thank you! just need some minor clarifications: 1) why Equals(Object obj), but not IEquatable<A>? I know for sure boxing/unboxing works pretty slow. 2) Do I get it correctly that for `Contains` call HashSet runs `GetHashCode` first and checks it over existing hash codes, than if such hash is found, it runs `Equals` to be recognize if instance is the same or new, right?

Comment: @YMC A hash set can be thought of as an array of lists. First it uses the result from `GetHashCode` to find which list to search then it uses `Equals` to find if the element exists inside the list. That is why if you use the default implimatation (by not passing in a `IEqualityComarer<T>` to the constructor) if two objects are equal but they return different hash codes the Hash set may or may not say the item exists inside the HashSet.

Comment: A hash set implementation may theoretically use `IEquatable<T>` but the documentation for `HashSet<T>` does not state that it does so. This is probably no omission in the documentation because you can use `IEquatable<T>` indirectly by passing `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to the constructor of `HashSet<T>` and the default comparer will use `IEquatable<T>` if the type implements it. See the MSDN for more details on how `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` works.

Comment: Scott, so it would work faster if I pass my own `EqualityComparer<A>` with no boxing/unboxing into constructor, right? In the case I do not need to implement `Equals(Object obj)`, correct?

Comment: The only thing I could say is try both and time it, I am willing to bet you will not find much of a difference.

Comment: You have a class and therefore there will be no boxing, just casting to `Object` an back and the overhead is minimal. And as stated above you can just use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to use an implementation of `IEquatable<T>` indirectly. It is hard to tell what will be faster because the differences are (probably) really small. Just do not care until you really experience performance problem. Than implement and profile all options and choose the fastest or best one. Guessing is just not good enough when optimizing code.